# How to best do a SQL left join null check where all must be null?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have table Person, who owns many Books, which cover many Subjects.
A Book might not yet have any Subjects assigned to them.

It's easy to query for Persons who own SOME Books that have no Subjects with a left join and a null check. e.g.:

```
select * from persons p 
  inner join person_book pb on pb.person_id = p.id
  left  join book_subject bs on bs.book_id = person_book.book_id
  where book_subject.book_id is null;
```

What is the best way to query for a Person who ONLY owns books with no established subjects?

I know I can find people with books, and people with at least 1 book with subjects, then find the difference. But is there a direct way?

(This would be in MySQL if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
select p.* 
from persons p 
inner join person_book pb on pb.person_id = p.id
left  join book_subject bs on bs.book_id = person_book.book_id
group by p.id
having count(bs.book_id) = 0
```